# ConfigurationErrorsException occurred

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a custom configuration for C# application. The app.config likes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="location" type ="FolderConfigSection.LocationConfig, FolderConfigSection"/>
  </configSections>
  <location>
    <folders>
      <add folder ="C:\Test1"/>
      <add folder ="C:\Test2" />
      <add folder ="C:\Test3" />
    </folders>
  </location>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

So I created two classes.

```
namespace FolderConfigSection
{
    public class LocationConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("folders")]
        public string Folder
        {
            get { return base["folder"] as string; }
            set { base["folder"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace FolderConfigSection
{
    public class FolderCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new FolderElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((FolderElement)element).Environment;
        }
    }

    public class FolderElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("folder", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Environment
        {
            get { return (string)this["folder"]; }
            set { this["folder"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

But I got an exception in my Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LocationConfig _locationConfig = (LocationConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("location");
        string firstFolder = _locationConfig.Folder;

    }
}
```

The exception is `The section name 'location' is reserved for <location> sections.`
Also I want to list all folders.

Comment: 1.  Don't use `<location>`.  2.  Use `ConfigurationElementCollection` for `<folder>`.

Comment: Code please, can't figure it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm restating what @Tim has answered in his comments.

1. Do not use `location` as section name. It is already reserved for [`<location>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element configuration. Just use other name, such as `locationConfig`.
2. Change the type of `Folder` property in `LocationConfig` class from `String` to `FolderCollection`. For clarity, you should probably change the property name `Folder` to its plural form `Folders`.
3. To list all the folders in `LocationConfig`, you just need to iterate the `Folders` collection property. You might also want to implement indexer on `FolderCollection` class, for an indexed access to `Folders` property, .

Putting it all in code:

### App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="locationConfig" type ="FolderConfigSection.LocationConfig, FolderConfigSection"/>
  </configSections>
  <locationConfig>
    <folders>
      <add folder ="C:\Test1"/>
      <add folder ="C:\Test2" />
      <add folder ="C:\Test3" />
    </folders>
  </locationConfig>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

### LocationConfig

```
namespace FolderConfigSection
{
  using System.Configuration;

  public class LocationConfig : ConfigurationSection
  {
    // Change the property type to FolderCollection, and
    // change the property name to `Folders` for clarity
    [ConfigurationProperty("folders")]
    public FolderCollection Folders
    {

      get { return base["folders"] as FolderCollection; }

      // the setter property isn't really needed here
      // set { base["folders"] = value; }
    }
  }

  public class FolderCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
  {
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
      return new FolderElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
      return ((FolderElement)element).Environment;
    }

    // indexer
    public FolderElement this[int index]
    {
      get { return BaseGet(index) as FolderElement; }      
    }
  }

  public class FolderElement : ConfigurationElement
  {
    [ConfigurationProperty("folder", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Environment
    {
      get { return (string)this["folder"]; }
      set { this["folder"] = value; }
    }
  }
}
```

### Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var locationConfig = (LocationConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("locationConfig");

    foreach (FolderElement folder in locationConfig.Folders)
    {
      // List all folders
      Console.WriteLine(folder.Environment);        
    }    

    // The first folder using indexer property
    Console.WriteLine(locationConfig.Folders[0].Environment);
  }
}
```